# Javascript: getAttribute() returns object NodeList?

Tags: javascript, html, nodelist

So what I'm trying to do is display a series of images based on the value of their HTML "id" attribute, which is also the name of their image file. I have written a Javascript code that will build the     `src` url for each image in the series (ignore the silly class name):

```
var idnum = document.querySelectorAll(".trollface")[0].getAttribute("id");

var tribe;
if (idnum < 116903 && idnum > 100000) {
    tribe = "Xana";
} else if (idnum < 213403 && idnum > 200000) {
    tribe = "Hemi";
} else {
    tribe ="Theri";
} 

var icon = document.getElementsByClassName("trollface");
for(var i = 0; i < icon.length; i++) {
    icon[i].src = "Dot_files/" + tribe + "/Icons/" + idnum + ".png";
}
```

This works fine, however as you can see with this, all the images will have the same     `src` as the first image in the series, which is not what I want.

The main problem I'm having is getting the values of each     `img`'s     `id` attribute and using them for their own     `img src` url.

I've tried iterating through the     `id`'s with

```
var idnum = document.querySelectorAll(".trollface");
for(var x = 0; x < idnum.length; x++) {
    idnum[x].getAttribute("id");
}
```

but in Chrome the value of     `idnum` is "[object%20NodeList]", which I presume is an object NodeList. This in turn leads to an ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (or something similar to that) because the output url becomes     `Dot_files/Theri/Icons/[object%20NodeList].png`, which doesn't exist.

With this I tried to convert the NodeList to an array, but still got the same result in Chrome.

So what I want to ask is: How come the     `getAttribute("id")` doesn't work when I iterate through all the elements with the class     `trollface`? It works fine if I just use the single line of code shown in the first snippet above. 
Also is it fine to iterate twice, as I iterated once with     `idnum` and a second time with     `icon`. Does this have anything to do with my problem?

Is there a workaround to this? I've been at this for a few days now, with no clue how to proceed.

Thanks for any help and sorry for the long post. I can provide more details/explanation if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't. You get that result if you concatenate the `idnum` variable not the returned value of the `getAttribute` method, `getAttribute` returns a *string* not a `nodeList`. You don't store the returned values of the `getAttribute` calls, where do you use them? `idnum[x].getAttribute("id");` by itself effectively doesn't do anything. That line gets the value and throws it away.

Also it seems you don't move the `if` logic into your second iteration.

```
var idnums = document.querySelectorAll(".trollface");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(idnums, function(el) {
    var tribe, id = el.id;
    if (id < 116903 && id > 100000) {
        tribe = "Xana";
    } else if (id < 213403 && id > 200000) {
        tribe = "Hemi";
    } else {
        tribe ="Theri";
    } 
    el.src = "Dot_files/" + tribe + "/Icons/" + id + ".png";
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. :) Guess I have to study and practice more Javascript.